Flutter IOS Build: PhaseScriptExecution Thin\ Binary Build Command Failing
I have a flutter app that I'm porting to ios. After running flutter build ios -v, the process succesfully sets up, installs dependencies, and compiles, but something goes wrong during the build phases.
/Users/liamhp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-aqpqbhigkgvvwqexwsikncfsedsl/Build/Interme
                         diates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh
                     Unhandled exception:
                     Null check operator used on a null value
                     
                     ...
              

                     Result bundle written to path:
                        /var/folders/51/2ypxj09x2tq8m09320t8ghlm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.pEfCUq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRNfKNo/temporary_xcresult_bundle

The following build commands failed:
                        PhaseScriptExecution Thin\ Binary
                        /Users/liamhp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-aqpqbhigkgvvwqexwsikncfsedsl/Build/Intermedia
                        tes.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh (in target
                        'Runner' from project 'Runner')
                     (1 failure)
[+110053 ms]  └─Compiling, linking and signing... (completed in 131.2s)
[        ] Xcode build done.                                           1464.1s
[  +16 ms] executing: xcrun xcresulttool get --path
/var/folders/51/2ypxj09x2tq8m09320t8ghlm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.pEfCUq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRNfKNo/temporary_xcresult_bundl
e --format json
{
  ...(build results dict)
  ...
  ...
  ...
                   "metrics" : {
                        "_type" : {
                          "_name" : "ResultMetrics"
                        },
                        "errorCount" : {
                          "_type" : {
                            "_name" : "Int"
                          },
                          "_value" : "1"
                        },
                        "warningCount" : {
                          "_type" : {
                            "_name" : "Int"
                          },
                          "_value" : "23"
                        }
                      }
                    }

}
[  +48 ms] Failed to build iOS app

I tried to look at the generated /var/folders/51/2ypxj09x2tq8m09320t8ghlm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.pEfCUq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRNfKNo/temporary_xcresult_bundle file, but the flutter_tools.pEfCUq folder is empty.
Looking for some insight on how best to debug this. Where should I look to figure out what's actually going wrong here?

try to do flutter clean
Also I recommend to reinstal pods
sh script:
flutter clean
cd ios/
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf Pods
rm Podfile.lock
cd ..
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
cd ..


Yeah I've already tried that and it doesn't fix the issue

My guess is that the error was in some sort of file corruption- I recloned the repo and it's fine now.
